# Find monthly interest rate from principal, monthly payment, and loan's term?

Tags: mortgage, interest-rate, calculation

Is there a formula to find the monthly interest rate required on a compounded interest fixed-rate mortgage loan, given the principal, the monthly payment, and the loan's term?

Answer (score 1):

The formula cannot be explicitly solved for the interest rate.  However, you can calculate the interest rate using formulas built into spreadsheets like Excel, calculators like the TI-83, any financial calculator, and using on-line calculators.

Comment: To add a thought, if there's no equation, how does excel solve this? It guesses. And then increases or decreases the rate until the error is less than some tiny amount.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That's basically what I found out. I wrote a script that tested interest rates until it found one that fit the givens. I'd select yours as the answer, but I can't.

Comment: @unitron6991 - Barry's answer is fine, I only wanted to clarify. The important thing is that you see and understand the solution, which is pretty cool.